# How to exit from function in vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Below code in vue.js 
function is :

```
    async up(id,point){     
            this.change = true
            const pId = id+'-'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

            db.collection('answer').doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
                if(doc.data().user_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid){
                    alert("You can't vote for your own post")
                    return
                }
            })

            db.collection('point').add({
               answer_user: pId,
               type: 'up',
            }).catch(function(error){
               console.error(error)
            });
        }
```

if the condition is true then show alert and return but return does not work and function is running mood and next Firebase query was execute

so how to exit the form function ??

Comment: What do you mean by "function is running mood"?

Comment: Next Firebase query was execute. i would exit from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, the following should do the trick:

```
up(id,point){     
        this.change = true
        const pId = id+'-'+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid

        db.collection('answer').doc(id).get()
          .then((doc) => {
             if(doc.data().user_id == firebase.auth().currentUser.uid){
                 alert("You can't vote for your own post");
                 return;  // You should not need any return anymore
             } else {
                 return db.collection('point').add({
                   answer_user: pId,
                   type: 'up',
                 });
             }
          })
          .catch(function(error){
             console.error(error)
          });
    }
```